# Error on a Future Method, But I Don't See How It's Being Called to Begin With

Tags: apex, error, future, method

The only awareness I have of the error is from this email notification :

```
Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 0051H000009g2Fv/00D1H000000NPnk

Failed to invoke future method 'public static void UpdateAccountsFuture(Set<Id>)' on class 'AccountTriggerHandler' for job id '7071H00006UyfG3'

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0011H00001ZTjDZQA1; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 01M1H00000fAzKsUAK; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []

Class.AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeInsertUpdate: line 371, column 1
Class.AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeUpdate: line 14, column 1
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 11, column 1: []

Class.AccountTriggerHandler.UpdateAccountsFuture: line 436, column 1
```

Here's the trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update, after insert, after update)
{
    boolean IsTriggerRunning = Toolbox.IsTriggerRunning('AccountTrigger');

    if (IsTriggerRunning && trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert) AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
    if (IsTriggerRunning && trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) AccountTriggerHandler.HandleAfterInsert(trigger.new);
    if (IsTriggerRunning && trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate) AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
    if (IsTriggerRunning && trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) AccountTriggerHandler.HandleAfterUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
}
```

Since the handler and the relevant method are each quite large, and since the point you'll see is that the future method call is precisely *not* present, hopefully the lines where the traced errors occur will suffice.

**"Class.AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeUpdate: line 14"**

```
12 public static void HandleBeforeUpdate(List<Account> newAccounts, Map<Id, Account> oldAccountMap)
13 {
14    AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeInsertUpdate(newAccounts, oldAccountMap);
15 }
```

**"Class.AccountTriggerHandler.HandleBeforeInsertUpdate: line 371"**

```
371 if(accountTeamMembersToDelete != null) delete accountTeamMembersToDelete;
```

**"Class.AccountTriggerHandler.UpdateAccountsFuture: line 436"**

```
431 @future
432 public static void UpdateAccountsFuture(Set<Id> accountIds)
433 {
434    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
435    for(Id accountId : accountIds) accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=accountId));
436    update accountsToUpdate;
437 }
```

I do know that the root of the error is a delete attempt in the AccountTriggerHandler class, in its HandleBeforeInsertUpdate method.  That class also has the future method named UpdateAccountsFuture.

But UpdateAccountsFuture is not being called in HandleBeforeInsertUpdate, nor anywhere else in the class.  So why is UpdateAccountsFuture throwing an error?

I searched the entire org's code for any UpdateAccountsFuture references.  The only place it's referenced/called is in a contact-trigger handler.  But, according to the error details, only the account trigger is firing.

How can an error in one of the class' methods cause the future method to also throw an error, when it's call is no where to be seen?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you debug without seeing `Trigger.AccountTrigger` nor `AccountTriggerHandler`?

Comment: The handler is quite large, as is the HandleBeforeInsertUpdate method.  I did not think it was all necessary, since it seemed to me the key was that the future method isn't called anywhere.

Comment: Your assessment is that it is not called. The error contradicts that assessment. Hence, it is necessary to see the code to determine where this discrepancy might come from.

Comment: To add to this: what could be happening is that the call is happening twice after an update in the first call. Without seeing more then how can we see. Though I do accept that hundreds of lines of code would be unwieldy.